# alter dataframe rows based on exogeneous array values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame `df`

```
A  B  C   D
0  0  0   0        
0  0  0   0        
0  0  0   0        
0  0  0   0        
0  0  0   0
```

and this array of events

events = [A C None None B]

I want to put 1 in the dataframe for every column where the corrsponding event occured, and nothing if None. So my result dataframe would be

```
A  B  C   D
1  0  0   0        
0  0  1   0        
0  0  0   0        
0  0  0   0        
0  1  0   0
```

The obvious manner would be to do the loop

```
for i, event in enumerate(events):
    if event is not None:
        df[event][i] = 1
```

Is there a more efficient manner when the number of rows is huge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) on the Series created from events and then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the column as in df.

```
events = ['A', 'C', None, None, 'B']
df_ = (pd.Series(events)
         .str.get_dummies()
         .reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=0)
      )
print (df_)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0
```

The `reindex` is really to add the missing column D here, in your real case, you may not need it

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy broadcasting to compare `df.columns` against `events` and populate values

```
import numpy as np

df[:] = (df.columns.to_numpy() == np.array(events)[:,None]).astype(int)

Out[44]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0
```

If you want more verbose

```
df[:] = np.equal(df.columns, np.array(events)[:,None]).astype(int)
```